# Same response being triggered for Different events

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I get the same response from the *MessageBox* when I click either on Help->Help... or File->Exit. I don't understand, where I am going wrong. (I am very new to wxPython)

I have this code snippet from **wxPython:**

```
class NewSheet(wx.Frame):
'''Anatomy of Sheet Frame'''
def __init__(self, parent, id, title,Nrows,Ncols,SheetName):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title, size = (550, 500))

    box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    menuBar = wx.MenuBar()        
    menu1 = wx.Menu()
    menuBar.Append(menu1, '&File')        
    menu1.Append(1,"&Exit")
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit,id = 2)

    menuBar.Append(menu8, '&Help')
    menu8.Append(1, "&Help...")
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnHelp, id=1)
    self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)
    self.SetSizer(box)




    notebook = wx.Notebook(self, -1, style=wx.RIGHT)
    sheet1 = MySheet(notebook,Nrows,Ncols)
    notebook.AddPage(sheet1, str(SheetName))
    sheet1.SetFocus()
    box.Add(notebook, 1, wx.EXPAND)

    self.Centre()
    self.Show(True)

def OnExit(self,event):
    self.Close(True)  #NOT WORKING!

    self.Exit() #NOT WORKING EITHER!


def OnHelp(self,event):
    wx.MessageBox("HTML Based Help System coming soon","Help System",wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION, self)
```

I get the same response from the MessageBox when I click either on Help->Help... or File->Exit. I don't understand, where I am going wrong. Can you please advise?

Comment: Don't specify the ids like that. Use wx.NewId or -1.

Comment: Hi Mike, I tried that, an exception was raised like this: assert source is None or hasattr(source, 'GetId')
AssertionError

Comment: self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit,id = 2) should be self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit,id = -1) or see http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2008/07/02/wxpython-working-with-menus-toolbars-and-accelerators/

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify different id values in menu?.Append and use the same ids in the Binds.  Try:

```
    em = menu1.Append(-1, "&Exit")
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, id=em)

    menuBar.Append(menu8, '&Help')
    hm = menu8.Append(-1, "&Help...")
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnHelp, id=hm)
```

This tells wx to pick and return new ids and then uses them.  Actually after a little bit you should find that for these two have predefined IDs `wx.ID_EXIT` & `wx.ID_HELP` see [here](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_stdevtid.html) for more so it is better to use:

```
    menu1.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, "&Exit")
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, id=wx.ID_EXIT)
    
    menuBar.Append(menu8, '&Help')
    menu8.Append(wx.ID_HELP, "&Help...")
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnHelp, id=wx.ID_HELP)
```

As you will find that on some platforms it helps by doing tricks like standard translations.

Comment: I did try that actually. I used two different ids, 1 and 2. I even tried three ways with -1, wx.ID_ANY and New_id() function. Stumbled upon different rror messages everytime. (New to wxPython)